# How can I isolate data-warehouse workloads from production/on-demand queries?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esx, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm using VMware's vSphere 6 and I'm considering consolidating several SQL servers, these servers have different usage profiles;

- On-demand burst reporting (Cognos/Data-warehouse)
- Interactive web usage (Business hours/with variable peak usage)

I want to avoid a degradation of service if these workloads are combined.

1. Does vSphere or SQL offer tools to guarantee a minimum/maximum CPU and Disk performance?
2. How granular is this control?
3. Should I use vSphere or SQL controls for this partitioning?

SiteMinder seems to have issues with the most recent version of SQL, or SQL 2014 for that matter, but outside of that dependency, we could use a newer version if needed.

Comment: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-60-resource-management-guide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This is staggeringly simple to do in vSphere using either resource pools (can get messy), vApps or directly applied to individual VMs.

What you do need to do is have a VM per class of work, you can't do this via vSphere if you run all of your workload in one SQL VM, it can't see that granularity. But if you have two or more VMs you can easily divide up the workload and limit what you want to do with CPU, memory, storage and network IO very simply. That said you will need to learn the basics of vSphere, we can't tell you every step, that's not what we're here for, we expect you to know the ABC's.

If you have to do this all in one VM then that control obviously must fall onto SQL's shoulders and I'm no expert on that one sorry.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to determine if I should divide the work in VMWare or SQL. This is what I thought about VM Ware, now need to see if there is a SQL approach.